# How to add a new organization in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

In official documentation of Hyperledger Fabric, if we want to add a new Organization to the network we only have folder named addOrg3 inside the examples (please see the attached screenshot.

If I want to add a 4th Organization. What is the process?

I tried to search on how to add the 4th organization but couldn't find.